# OpenGL 2D faded circle being stretched/compressed by the resolution

Tags: glsl

I'd like my faded lighting (based on distance from a point) to be a perfect circle no matter the resolution. Currently, the light is only a circle if the height and width of the window are equal.

This is what it looks like right now:

[image]

My fragment shader looks like this:

```
precision mediump float;
#endif

#define MAX_LIGHTS  10

// varying input variables from our vertex shader
varying vec4 v_color;
varying vec2 v_texCoords;

// a special uniform for textures
uniform sampler2D u_texture;
uniform vec2 u_resolution;
uniform float u_time;

uniform vec2 lightsPos[MAX_LIGHTS];
uniform vec3 lightsColor[MAX_LIGHTS];
uniform float lightsSize[MAX_LIGHTS];

uniform vec2 cam;

uniform vec2 randPos;

uniform bool dark;

void main()
{
    vec4 lights = vec4(0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0);
    float ratio = u_resolution.x/u_resolution.y;
    vec2 st = gl_FragCoord.xy/u_resolution;
    vec2 loc = vec2(.5 + randPos.x, 0.5 + randPos.y);

    for(int i = 0; i < MAX_LIGHTS; i++)
    {
        if(lightsSize[i] != 0.0)
        {
            // trying to reshape the light
            // vec2 st2 = st;
            // st2.x *= ratio;

            float size = 2.0/lightsSize[i];
            float dist = max(0.0, distance(lightsPos[i], st)); // st here was replaced with st2 when experimenting

            lights = lights + vec4(max(0.0, lightsColor[i].x - size * dist), max(0.0, lightsColor[i].y - size * dist), max(0.0, lightsColor[i].z - size * dist), 0.0);
        }
    }

    if(dark)
    {
        lights.r = max(lights.r, 0.075);
        lights.g = max(lights.g, 0.075);
        lights.b = max(lights.b, 0.075);
    }
    else
    {
        lights.r += 1.0;
        lights.g += 1.0;
        lights.b += 1.0;
    }

    gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoords) * lights;
}
```

I tried reshaping the light by multiplying the `x` value of the pixel by the `ratio` of the screen width to the screen height but that caused the lights to be out of place. I couldn't figure out anything that would put them back in their correct place while maintaining their shape.

EDIT: the displacement is determined by my camera's position in my libgdx scene.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you need is to rescale the difference between light position and fragment position

```
vec2 dr = st-lightsPos[i];
dr.x*=ratio;
float dist = length(dr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try normalizing `st` like that

```
vec2 st = (gl_FragCoord.xy - .5*u_resolution.xy) / min(u_resolution.x, u_resolution.y);
```

So that coordinates of your fragments are in range `[-1; 1]` for `y` and `[-ratio/2; ratio/2]` where `ratio = u_resolution.x/u_resolution.y`

You can also make it `[0; 1]` for `y` and `[0; ratio]` for `x` by doing

```
vec2 st = gl_FragCoord.xy / min(u_resolution.x, u_resolution.y);
```

But the former is more convenient in many cases

Comment: The first suggestion displaces the lights on both the `x and y axes`. Whereas the latter displaces only the `x axis` in (I think) the exact same way as in my attempt to fix it.
I should mention that each light in my libgdx scene is displaced according to my camera position, I've made that change to my original question.