# normalizing a radius in a shader via mix

Tags: shader, godot, fragment-shader

I am trying to understand this Godot shader:

```
shader_type canvas_item;
render_mode unshaded;

uniform float circle_size : hint_range(0.0, 1.05);
uniform float screen_width;
uniform float screen_height;

void fragment() {
    float ratio = screen_width / screen_height;
    float dist = distance(vec2(0.5, 0.5), vec2(mix(0.5, UV.x, ratio), UV.y));
    COLOR.a = step(circle_size, dist);
}
```

and I don't understand how the mix function normalizes the circle (or the x value for the distance to the center, to be a bit more precise). I found the formula for mix and it is:

```
mix(x,y,a) = x * (1−a) + y * a
```

But it doesn't seem to make sense, I did 10 samples in excel and got this:

```
x     y     a       mix
0.5   0.1   1.77    -0.208
0.5   0.2   1.77    -0.031
0.5   0.3   1.77    0.146
0.5   0.4   1.77    0.323
0.5   0.5   1.77    0.5
0.5   0.6   1.77    0.677
0.5   0.7   1.77    0.854
0.5   0.8   1.77    1.031
0.5   0.9   1.77    1.208
0.5   1     1.77    1.385
```

(my screen resolution is 1280x720; so the ration is 1280 / 720 = 1.77)

I don't get how these numbers create a normalized circle where x and y have the same distance to the center; I just know that it works.

Also, I know there is a similar question: [how do i normalize a circle drawn in glsl so the resolution doesn't stretch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66191819/how-do-i-normalize-a-circle-drawn-in-glsl-so-the-resolution-doesnt-stretch) but I primarily care about the purpose of mix in this example.